# Dropdown fixed position and formatting not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive menu bar that has a dropdown list which is named three. However, I cannot make its format same with the other title and it moves once it is being hovered. Is there any way that the format title of three be the same as one, two, four and five? And when it is being hovered, is it possible that its position be in a fixed place? Please help. I already tried inline but it doesn't work either. And kindly run the snippet in full screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\">  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script> 
 <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel = "icon" href = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/data-fiveence-46-1170621.png" type = "image/x-icon"> 
</head>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel&display=swap');
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.strips {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
 .strips__strip {
  will-change: width, left, z-index, height;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
  left: 60vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
  left: 80vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) .strip__content {
  background:#29363B;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip1;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) .strip__content {
  background: #EA495F;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip2;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) .strip__content {
  background: #F4837D;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip3;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) .strip__content {
  background: #FAA664;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip4;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) .strip__content {
  background: #99B998;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip5;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip {
   min-height: 20vh;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
   top: 20vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
   top: 40vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
   top: 60vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
   top: 80vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
}
 .strips .strip__content {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(3) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
 .strips .strip__content:before {
  <!-- content: ""; -->
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.05;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scaleY(1) translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips .strip__inner-text {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip--expanded {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: default;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip--expanded {
   min-height: 100vh;
 }
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.05;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__title {
  opacity: 0;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__inner-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
 .strip__title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strip__title {
   font-size: 28px;
 }
}
 .strip__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
  top: 3vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
 .strip__close--show {
  opacity: 1;
}
 @keyframes strip1 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip2 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip3 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip4 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip5 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

 body {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
 h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
 .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
 h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
 p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
p {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent 5px
     );
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100%;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent
     );
}

:root {
  --mainColor: white;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

</style>

<body>
 <section class="strips">
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
          <p class="strip__title" onclick="one()">one</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <p class="strip__title" onclick="#">two</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
  <div class="navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <p class="strip__title" style="margin-left:-15px">three</p>
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="sdct()">two</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="four()">four</a>
       </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
     <p class="strip__title" onclick="#">four</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <p class="strip__title" onclick="">five</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <i class="fa fa-close strip__close"></i>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; /* add a width */
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; /*position is changes (relative --> absolute)*/
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
```

Comment: it Would be better if you provide some description about what the code do